# Get lost in parameter passing by reference, by value

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a bag container. The problem that beyond me occurs when I am overloading the `=` operator.

```
Zsak& Zsak::operator =(const Zsak& a)
{
  (*this).V=a.V;
  (*this).elemsz=a.elemsz;
  return *this;
}
```

with this header:

```
class Zsak
{
public:
    Zsak (){V=new Elem[100];}
    Zsak (const Zsak & a)
    {
        *this=a;
    }
    Zsak(int meret)
    {
        V=new Elem[meret];
    }
    ~Zsak(){delete[] V;}
    Zsak& operator -(const Zsak& b);
    Zsak& operator =(const Zsak& a);
    void Zsak_Ba(int e);
    void Zsak_Bol(int e);
    bool Uress();
    int E_Hany(int e) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out,const Zsak& z);
private:
    Elem  *V;
    int elemsz=0;

};
```

The `Zsak_Ba` puts an element into the bag;

The `Zsak_Bol` draws out an element from the bag;

What I observed through testing  is that the address of `const Zsak a` identify with the address of `*this` .

with this context

```
Zsak z(5),c(5);
z.Zsak_Ba(1);
z.Zsak_Ba(1);
z.Zsak_Ba(1);
z.Zsak_Ba(2);
z.Zsak_Ba(2);
z.Zsak_Ba(2);
z.Zsak_Ba(4);
Zsak d=z;
d.Zsak_Bol(1);
cout<<z<<endl<<d;
```

It prints :

```
1 2
2 3
4 1

1 2
2 3
4 1
```

And what it really should print is:

```
1 3
2 3
4 1

1 2
2 3
4 1
```

What i should do to obtain this?
What i am doing wrong? And why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're only copying a pointer here: `(*this).V=a.V;`. So now two objects point to the same data.

Comment: And what to do to eliminate this?

Comment: Assign all the elements of the array pointed at by the RHS object to those of the array pointed at by the LHS object.

Comment: Forgive me @juanchopanza but can u give me an example ?

Comment: Note that `Zsak d=z;` invokes the copy constructor, not your assignment operator.

Comment: But if my assignment operator its working the copy constructor works also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only copy the pointers (and not the content) in you assignment operator.

```
Zsak& Zsak::operator =(const Zsak& a)
{
  if (this == &a) { // or std::addressof(a)
    return *this;
  }

  delete[] V;

  elemsz=a.elemsz;
  V=new Elem[elemsz];
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < elemsz; ++i) {
    V[i] = a.V[i];
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Additionally, I don't see where the `elemsz` is being updated (outside the member initialisation). I would imagine it would be in constructors.

```
Zsak(int meret)
{
    V=new Elem[meret];
    elemsz = meret;
}
```

And

```
Zsak ()
{
  V=new Elem[100];
  elemsz = 100;
}
```

It may also be worth noting that often a "copy-swap" is used to implement the assignment operator, and a full copy in the copy constructor (basically the other way around from what you have it).

The "copy-swap" would look like

```
Zsak (const Zsak & a) : elemsz(a.elemsz)
{
  V = new Elem[elemsz];
  for (int i = 0; i < elemsz; ++i) { // copy the contents
    V[i] = a.V[i];
  }
}

Zsak& Zsak::operator =(const Zsak& a)
{
  Zsak temp(a);
  std::swap(this->elemsz, temp.elemsz);
  std::swap(this->V, temp.V);
  return *this;
}
```

It incurs some overhead with on assignment to self, a test for self assignment can be added for this if needed.

Understanding that this is a task to use and implement dynamic memory, it may be best to re-factor out the `Elem` array and its management outside the of the main class. It is generally easier to maintain and correct bugs and issues as they arise.

Comment: @ Niall The `V=new Elem[elemsz]` will be deleted when the deconstruct calls? I set `elemsz` here:`private: Elem *V; int elemsz=0;` It is not good to do this?

Comment: @lero, yes the `delete[]` will be called in the destructor. Setting the `elemsz` there is a good idea, but you need to update it when you allocate the memory in `V`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was watching this code for hours...Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `vector<Elem>` instead of manual dynamic memory, you do not need any user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator. It will just work. This is the preferred solution. Let C++ do the work for you.

Comment: I know this...But this is task :) I must do it dynamically.